# go install cross compile std library, shared, gives error: warnings treated as errors

Tags: go

I am trying to cross compile the go std library with this command:

```
CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=/custom/path/to/g++ GOARCH=arm GOARM=5 go install -buildmode=shared -v std
```

And I get this error:

```
runtime/cgo
# runtime/cgo
In file included from gcc_context.c:8:
libcgo.h:97:15: error: unnecessary parentheses in declaration of '_cgo_get_context_function' [-Werror=parentheses]
   97 | extern void (*(_cgo_get_context_function(void)))(struct context_arg*);
      |               ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

The g++ version is 11.2. (custom built).

Is there any way to disable the warnings-as-errors, so I can progress with the build? I have tried setting CFLAGS="-Wno-error", (also CXXFLAGS)

**EDIT**
I figured it out, but this just let to more issues. Set CGO_CFLAGS="-Wno-error". Now I get this error:

```
gcc_libinit.c: In function 'int _cgo_try_pthread_create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)':
libcgo.h:10:14: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'timespec*' [-fpermissive]
   10 | #define nil ((void*)0)
      |             ~^~~~~~~~~
      |              |
      |              void*
gcc_libinit.c:110:32: note: in expansion of macro 'nil'
  110 |                 nanosleep(&ts, nil);
      |                                ^~~
```

is this a bug in the cgo code itself? Should I report this as a bug-ticket to the go-project?